# Comparing key-values in a dictionary as electrical usage per day

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, python-itertools

I have list of list that's recording the electrical usage for a particular building. The sampling is done every 30 minutes. I'm using a dictionary to group the samples by day/month, I figured after that I could take the max value for each day and subtract the following - previous day, so I can get the total for that day. Where the total is kilowatt-hour.

One of the issues I'm having is accounting for the first max value of the first day/month, because I have nothing to compare that with because that was the first max sample? If there's a better approach please tell?
The way I was planning to handle that is during that time just find the difference between min max until I get enough data.

I have created a list of list as an example. The first column will be the month and second recorded value.

The following shows the dictionary grouped by month and then finding the max value.
You can see that once the max values and difference are found that month 1 will not be accounted for? The result I should get is {1:4, 2:10, 3:25} which is total by month and then
{1:39} for the year?

```
dict1 = {1: [1, 3, 4, 5], 2: [7, 8, 9, 10, 15], 3: [20, 25, 40]}
dict2 = {1: 5, 2: 15, 3: 40}
```

Here is the code so far, I commented out the operations to get the total for the year and by month because my approaches weren't working?

```
list1 =     [[1, 1],
             [1, 1],
             [1, 0],
             [1, 3],
             [1, 4],
             [1, 5],  # max
             [2, 7],
             [2, 8],
             [2, 9],
             [2, 10],
             [2, 15],  # max
             [3, 20],
             [3, 25],
             [3, 40]]  # max

    # using min/max of each day/month I'll miss the usage between the last value for the 
    #  day/month and
    #  first value of next day/month.
    #  ex: day 1: 5 - 1 = 4 , day 2: = 9 - 7 = 2, day 3: 40 - 12 = 28
    #  missed usage from  5 to 7 and 9 to 12

    #  taking the difference between max values of each day/month
    #  ex: day 1: = 5, day 2: = 9, day 3 = 40  day 1 = 4, day 2 = 31
    #
    # 
    dict1 = {}
    dict2 = {}
    dict3 = {}

    for i, j in list1:
        if j > 0:  # Samples will always be greater than zero so eliminate any sample that's not.
            dict1.setdefault(i, []).append(j)  # Group all the samples by day/month.
            dict1[i] = sorted(list(set(dict1[i])))  # Check for duplicate samples
            max_ = max(dict1[i])
            dict2[i] = max_

            

    print(dict1)
    print(dict2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you need using dictionary comprehensions:

1. Read `list1` into `dict1`:

```
list1 = [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5],  
         [2, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9], [2, 10], [2, 15],  
         [4, 20], [4, 25], [4, 40]]
months = sorted(set(l[0] for l in list1))
dict1 = {m: sorted(set(l[1] for l in list1 if l[0]==m and l[1]>0)) for m in months}
>>> dict1
{1: [1, 3, 4, 5], 2: [7, 8, 9, 10, 15], 4: [20, 25, 40]}
```

2. Manipulate `dict1` to get the differences:

You can simply use indices -1 and 0 for the maximum and minimum values as the lists are sorted for each date.

```
dict2 = {m: dict1[m][-1]-dict1[m-1][-1] if m-1 in dict1 and dict1[m][0]>=dict1[m-1][-1] else dict1[m][-1]-dict1[m][0] for i, m in enumerate(months)}
>>> dict2
{1: 4, 2: 10, 4: 20}
```

3. Get the total for the year using `dict2`:

```
dict3 = {1: sum(dict2.values())}
>>> dict3
{1: 34}
```

Comment: If I modify list1 lets say to have recorded month 1, 2, and 4,  or any out of order month then the code assigned to dict2 breaks. the result is now {1: 4, 2: 10, 4: 20}, the keys of the dictionary throw the code off. I tested this because lets say the system goes down and I miss a only month or however long I don't have recorded data for that time?

Comment: If you have only data for months 1, 2, and 4, what should `dict2` be?

Comment: let me clarify this with list1 modified once again:  [[1, 1],
             [1, 1],
             [1, 0],
             [1, 3],
             [1, 4],
             [1, 5], 
             [2, 7],
             [2, 8],
             [2, 9],
             [2, 10],
             [2, 15], 
             [4, 20],
             [4, 25],
             [4, 40]]

Comment: So, to be clear, in this case, you'll be taking a 2-month difference?

Comment: let me take step back, also the recorded meter usage is always increasing unless the meter gets reset to 0 or replaced, if i recorded for months 1 ,2,and 4 because I wasn't able to communicate with meter during month 3 then I would suspect if the meter doesnt have a problem and it was just a communication issue the value would be higher at that time! so I would just make an assumption for month 3 based on the data

Comment: every month or missed period i miss, I would have to just take the min and max difference since I cant compare to anything previous? does that make sense? @not_speshal

Comment: So then shouldn't `dict2` be {1: 4, 2: 10, 4: 20} and not {1: 4, 2: 10, 4: 25} like you said? And therefore my original answer should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235310/discussion-between-not-speshal-and-musclemania05).

Comment: I had a typo that i fixed yes should be  {1: 4, 2: 10, 4: 20}, but if you have a list such as this  [[1, 1],
             [1, 1],
             [1, 0],
             [1, 3],
             [1, 4],
             [1, 5],
             [5, 7],
             [5, 8],
             [5, 9],
             [5, 10],
             [5, 15],  
             [4, 20],
             [4, 25],
             [4, 40]]

Comment: what purpose "for i, m in enumerate(months)"  since "i" is just the iteration count and is not really serving no purpose?  That could simply be "for m in months"